# How to remove an IIS Manager User using PowerShell

Tags: iis, configuration

I can't seem to figure out how to remove a IIS Manager User using PowerShell. I'm using Microsoft Server Core, and I can't do this through Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager since the user I login with is the user I need to remove. Any idea how I can do this through PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Management")   
[Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthentication]::DeleteUser("UserName")
```